# Is it possible to use two colours for font in one jquery string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner at coding, and would like to know if it is possible to use two different colors in one jquery string? For example, if I wanted to make the word 'Message' to be in black (which it already is), and 'Example' to be in a light grey, what would I have to do?

```
var textarray = [
    "\"Message\"<br>Example",
  ];
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xL2g23oz/2/

Thank you for the help

Comment: what's a jquery string? how does one put a single colour in a string?

Comment: Use `.html()` with `<span style="red">text</span>` will work but that is not safe. Color information needs to be handled differently.

Comment: you can only give color to the string if you use `html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: Okay so do you find that <span style='color:green'>Example</span>" would be a bad solution? And now that it is changed to html() what would I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var textarray = [
    "\"Message\"<br><span style=\"color: #d3d3d3\">Example</span>",
  ];
```

---

Or something as simple as adding a class

```
var textarray = [
    "\"Message\"<br><span class=\"color-lightgrey\">Example</span>",
  ];
```

css:

```
.color-lightgrey { color: #d3d3d3; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, it works. But I received a comment on my post stating its not safe, but I don't understand why. Do you happen to know if this would be okay to use?

Comment: It's safe. Is it best practice to do it the way you are? Probably not, but that's a much bigger question. Adding style or classes to HTML is common and there's no security issue. My answer addresses your original question, and it will work as you wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Working Example (JS Fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/xL2g23oz/4/

Just modify **textarray** as:

```
var textarray = [

  "\"Message\"<br><span style = 'color: #bbb;'>Example</span>" 

];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved only by CSS. For your example, I hope it would be helpful.
It will always make the first line red.

```
#random_text::first-line {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gs4y5m7/)